# Dynamically create tabs/tables in Visualforce based on field sets

Tags: visualforce, customer-community, datatable

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have multiple `Objects` that are related to a `Contact`. In a Visualforce page, I want to create a tab for each of these related `Objects`; then, in their respective tabs, I want to create a table that shows values defined in a field set for each object.

I've approached this problem from a few different angles, and nothing seems to be working.

Initially, and with some success, I attempted to retrieve all related `Objects` from Salesforce and use the `fieldLabel` and `relationshipName` to populate the table. Something like this:

Controller:

```java
public Map<String, String> getRelatedObjects() {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, String> relatedObjects = new Map<String, String>();

    //Loop through child relationships and retrieve the label/name of our related objects
    for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: result.getChildRelationships()) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult childObject = cr.getChildSObject().getDescribe();

        //So we don't retrieve unwanted relationships, we prefix ours with 'RRP'
        //Maybe attempt to come up with a more dynamic solution in the future?
        if (childObject.Name.contains('RRP')) {
            relatedObjects.put(cr.getRelationshipName(), childObject.LabelPlural);
        }
    }
    return relatedObjects;
}
```

VF:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <apex:repeat value="{! RelatedObjects }" var="ro">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#{! RelatedObject[ro] }">{! RelatedObjects[ro] }</a>
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <apex:repeat value="{! RelatedObjects }" var="ro">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="{! RelatedObjects[ro] }" role="tabpanel">
            <apex:dataTable value="{! Contact[ro] }" var="program">
                <!---TO DO: Link fields to fieldsets-->
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="#">{! program.Name }</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
           </apex:dataTable>
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</div>
```

This worked well for creating the tabs that I need, but breaks when creating the table. It seems that `<apex:dataTable>` just doesn't like bracket notation, as referencing the relationship directly (with `Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r`) works, but using brackets results in an error.

> Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r

This is my first time working with Salesforce, so I'm not aware of all methods that are available to me. I would greatly appreciate some incite if someone could point my in the right direction?

**EDIT:** Added update code.

```java
public Map<String, Contact> getRelatedObjects() {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Contact> relatedObjects = new Map<String, Contact>();

    //Loop through child relationships and retrieve the label/name of our related objects
    for (Schema.ChildRelationship cr: result.getChildRelationships()) {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult childObject = cr.getChildSObject().getDescribe();

        //So we don't retrieve unwanted relationships, we prefix ours with 'RRP'
        //Maybe attempt to come up with a more dynamic solution in the future?
        if (childObject.Name.contains('RRP')) {
            String relationshipName = cr.getRelationshipName();
            relatedObjects.put(childObject.LabelPlural, queryContact(relationshipName));
        }
    }
    return relatedObjects;
}

public Contact queryContact(String relationshipName) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, (SELECT Name FROM ' + relationshipName + ') FROM Contact LIMIT 1';
    system.debug('<<<<<<' + query + '>>>>>>>');
    Contact c = Database.query(query);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your code at line

```
 <apex:dataTable value="{! Contact[ro] }" var="program">
```

You are trying to access child record from master but dynamic visualforce Binding does not works like that.

> Dynamic Visualforce binding is supported for standard and custom objects. Dynamic bindings take the following general form:

```
reference[expression]
```

> where
>
> reference evaluates to either an sObject, an Apex class, or a global variable
>
> expression evaluates to a string that is the name of a field, or a related object. If a related object is returned, it can be used to recursively select fields or further related objects.

Example : 
{!myContact['Account'][fieldname]}
But what you are trying is {!Account['Contact'][fieldname]}
 which is wrong.
Secondly when when  you are replacing Contact[ro] with Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r You are getting list of RRP_GrantPrograms associates with your case which you have to query like.

```
Contact c = [select Id, (Select Id from RRP_GrantPrograms__r) from Contact LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: Thank you, this produces the desired result. However, this only works when the `FROM` clause is hard-coded, even in dynamic SOQL.

`Contact c = Database.query('SELECT Id, (Select Name From ' + relationshipName + ') from Contact LIMIT 1');`

Produces:
>Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r

`Contact c = Database.query('SELECT Id, (Select Name From RRP_GrantPrograms__r') from Contact LIMIT 1');`

Does not.

Comment: Can you post code ..Because Ideally it should work. did you try to debug relationshipName .

Comment: I've added the updated code, and yes, relationshipName is the correct string.